# DraftJS Modifier.insertText(): Insert Unicode

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, emojione

I've list of emojis. Each of them has its own unicode. With Modifier.insertText(), I would like to insert them to the text.

```
_addEmoji(text) {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    const selection = editorState.getSelection();
    const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const txt = '&#x' + text + ';';
    let nextEditorState = EditorState.createEmpty();
    if (selection.isCollapsed()) {
      const nextContentState = Modifier.insertText(contentState, selection, txt);
      nextEditorState = EditorState.push(
        editorState,
        nextContentState,
        'insert-characters'
      );
    } else {
      const nextContentState = Modifier.replaceText(contentState, selection, text);
      nextEditorState = EditorState.push(
        editorState,
        nextContentState,
        'insert-characters'
      );
    }
    this.onChange(nextEditorState);
  }
```

I expect to see 😄 inserted to the editor but it displays row `&#x1f604;` instead.

I've inserted `<meta charset="utf-8" />` to `<head />` and the list of emoji is rendered perfectly. The main problem is the draftjs editor displays raw unicode instead of the emoji.

Any thoughts to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: So you have included the unicode in the HTML and now it works fine? What is the problem here?, I don't understand.

Comment: The charset should be specified in the html document's head. Are you using a different charset?

Answer (score 4):

Cause insertText will parse your `&` to `&amp;` with HTML encoding.

You should type the character directly there, or use `String.fromCharCode`.

e.g.:

```
Modifier.insertText(contentState, selection, );
```

or

```
Modifier.insertText(contentState, selection, String.fromCharCode(0xd83d, 0xde04));
```

Cause

```
''.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); //d83d
''.charCodeAt(1).toString(16); //de04
```